# CSS show scrollbar only when max-width reached

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have two child divs in a parent div with `display: flex`.

Here's a dummy snippet to represent my situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="display: flex;">
        <div style="width: 100%;">
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long
            text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long
            text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long
            text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long
            text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text
            long text long text long text
        </div>
        <div style="width: fit-content; max-width: 60%; display: flex; overflow: auto;">
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; background-color: red; margin-right: 15px;"></div>
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; background-color: red; margin-right: 15px;"></div>
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; background-color: red; margin-right: 15px;"></div>
            <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; background-color: red; margin-right: 15px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

The content in the right div will be added dynamically, in this case we have red boxes. So it may contain 0 or more of those red boxes.

What I want is:

- I want for the right div to expand as long as it doesn't reach it's max set width of 60% and after it does I want for a horizontal scrollbar to appear for that div.
- As the right div expands (until it reaches 60% of the max width) the left div will decrease in size.

The snippet above will do this if I remove `overflow: auto` from the right div, but when it reaches it's maximum of 60% the horizontal scrollbar will appear for the whole page instead of only appearing for the right div area.

And if I leave `overflow: auto` then the scrollbar will be there from the beginning (like you can see in the image, and I only want it to appear after max-width of 60% has been exceeded).

How would I handle this?

EDIT:

Here is codepen link: https://codepen.io/transcend/pen/wvWyZvK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS as below:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 40%;
}
.box-container {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

I have used overflow-x: auto; which helps to generate a horizontal scroll bar. Hope this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Below line to your Class or Id

> overflow:auto;

Like this

```
 .box{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    }
```